# django: got an unexpected keyword argument while accessing ForeignKey _id-Field in Manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class Mentorship (models.Model):
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='mentor_user_id')
    mentee = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='mentee_user_id')

    objects = MentorshipManager()

    def clean(self):
        print(self.mentor_id)  # is set and printed to stdout
        print(self.mentee_id)  # is set and printed to stdout

        if Mentorship.objects.is_mentor(self.mentor_id, self.mentee_id):
            raise ValidationError(_('This user is already a mentor.'))
```

The manager has a function to check if someone is already a mentor of another user, which is called while `clean()`ing the instance:

```
def is_mentor_for_goal(self, mentor_id, mentee_id, personal_goal_id):
    if self.exists(mentor_id=mentor_id, mentee_id=mentee_id):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

However I always get an exception while accessing the `mentor_id` or `mentee_id` attribute in exists:

```
Django Version:     1.6.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    exists() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mentor_id'
```

Is there a reason why I cannot access the _id field within the manager? I just don't understand why the field is accessible in the (unsaved) instance, but not in the manager.

Comment: Try this : `mentor__id=mentor_id` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things `mentor__id` will only work in queryset methods, not things like `print`. You should also use `pk` instead of `id`, here is how it would work:

```
class Mentorship(models.Model):
    mentor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='mentor_user_id')
    mentee = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='mentee_user_id')

    objects = MentorshipManager()

    def clean(self):
        print(self.mentor.pk)  # is set and printed to stdout
        print(self.mentee.pk)  # is set and printed to stdout

        if Mentorship.objects.filter(mentor=self.mentor).exists():
            raise ValidationError(_('This user is already a mentor.'))

def is_mentor_for_goal(self, mentor_id, mentee_id, personal_goal_id):
    return self.exists(mentor__pk=mentor_id, mentee__pk=mentee_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh... man... It should be called

```
if self.filter(mentor_id=mentor_id, mentee_id=mentee_id).exists()
```

Thanks for your comments